# Parse PDF with ABCPDF

Tags: abcpdf

I want to parse a PDF document I download with ABCPDF, but I cant find any elements in the document or how to reach them and iterate them.  I want to parse out some text.

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
                                var bytes = webClient.DownloadData("http://test.com/test.pdf");

                                var doc = new Doc();
                                doc.Read(bytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Doc.GetText](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf9net/source/5-abcpdf/doc/1-methods/gettext.htm) method to extract content from the current page, specifying the format in which content is to be returned.

```
doc.PageNumber = 1;
string pageContent = doc.GetText("Text");
```

The example above will return plain text in layout order. Specifying "SVG" or "SVG+" returns additional information along with the text, such as style and position.